# R how to use mapply with a data table and two lists of column names

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with 2x data columns and two id columns. The id columns are years with values (X2010, X2015, X2020, etc) and countries (cty1, cty2, etc). For each country, the first set of data columns (f1, f2, f3, etc) has a value only in the first row (X2010) and NAs in the rest of the rows. The second set of columns (x.f1, x.f2, x.f3, etc) has NA in the first row and different values in the rest of the rows. I want to replace the NAs in the first set of columns with the following recursive structure for each country.

```
f1.X2015 = f1.X2010 * x.f1.X2015
f1.X2020 = f1.X2015 * x.f1.X2020
...
```

I have tried the following

```
foods <- c("f1", "f2", "f3")
x.foods <- c("x.f1", "x.f"2, "x.f3")
res <- c("res.f1", "res.f2", "res.f3")
f.cumprod <- function(x,y) {return(first(x) * cumprod(replace(y), 1,1) * NA^(.I= 1))}
```

Here's the data table structure that I thought would work to generate values for the res columns.

```
DT[,(res) := mapply(FUN = f.cumprod, x = .SD, y = list(x.foods)), .SDcols = foods, by = c("cty")]
```

Here's a simplified version  for just one country

```
set.seed(24)

 dt <- data.table(cty = c(rep("cty1", 5), rep("cty2", 5), rep("cty3", 5)), year = rep(c("X2010", "X2015", "X2020", "X2025", "X2030"), 3), 
             f1 = rep(c(0.9883415, rep(NA, 4)), 3), f2 = rep(c(1.0685221, rep(NA, 4)), 3), f3 = rep(c(1.0664189, rep(NA, 4)), 3), 
           x.f1 = rep(c(NA, rep(rnorm(4))), 3),   x.f2 = rep(c(NA, rep(rnorm(4))), 3),   x.f3 = rep(c(NA, rep(rnorm(4))), 3))
```

And a kludgy, and slowwww, way to get the result for one of the food items, f1.

```
dt.subset <- dt[, c("f1", "x.f1"), with = FALSE]

for (i in 2:nrow(dt.subset)) {
  dt.subset$f1[i] <- dt.subset$f1[i - 1] * dt.subset$x.f1[i]
}
```

Since I want to do this for about 170 countries and 20 food items (and with 4 scenarios), I'm hoping there is a solution along the lines of the DT code above.

Comment: Which one you want to apply.  Is it the second function or first.  BTW, there is some typo in your example

Comment: I'd like to use f.cumprod or some version of it (this is something you gave me in a different post). If I understand how cumprod works, the for loop gives the same result as the f.cumprod function for a single country and food. Am I understanding your question about which function correctly?

Comment: Your function seems to have typos i.e. `.I=1`.  Is it `.I==1` ?  It would be better to have an example data that uses the `mapply` because `"cty"` is not in the `dt`

Comment: In addition to that it is not clear what `replace` is doing `cumprod(replace(y), 1,1)`  Here, I think there is a mismatch of brackets

Comment: There was a typo. It should be `.I==1`. The replace xxx structure comes from some code in a comment from @Frank in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032823/r-rowdies-iteration-on-a-data-table-again.

Comment: I mistyped above the f.cumprod function is based on something @Frank gave me in the question in the comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I have update d my solution with the new data.  But, your first function i.e. `f.cumprod` is not working with the `mapply` code as there are some issues in the function `Error in replace(y) : argument "values" is missing, with no default`

Comment: I changed the `f.cumprod`.  Please check if that works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are looking for a recursive function (for a single 'cty')

```
dt.subset[, f1 := Reduce(`*`, x.f1[-1], init = f1[1], accumulate = TRUE)]
```

Or with `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
dt.subset[, f1 := accumulate(x.f1[-1], ~ .x * .y, .init = f1[1])]
```

---

Based on the OP's data 'dt', we could `melt` into 'long' forma, then apply the function with `accumulate`, `dcast` back to 'wide'

```
out <- dcast(melt(dt, measure = patterns("^f\\d+", "^x\\.f\\d+"))[, 
  accumulate(value2[-1], ~ .x * .y, .init = value1[1]), .(variable, cty)], 
  cty + rowid(variable) ~ variable, value.var = "V1")
nm1 <- grep("^f\\d+$", names(dt), value = TRUE)
setnames(out, -(1:2), nm1)
```

and then `set` the columns of interest with the new values

```
for(j in nm1) set(dt, i= NULL, j= j, value = out[[j]])
dt
#     cty  year          f1         f2           f3       x.f1       x.f2         x.f3
# 1: cty1 X2010  0.98834150  1.0685221  1.066418900         NA         NA           NA
# 2: cty1 X2015 -0.53951661  0.9055298 -0.904717849 -0.5458808  0.8474600 -0.848370044
# 3: cty1 X2020 -0.28949668  0.2408908 -0.002091656  0.5365853  0.2660220  0.002311942
# 4: cty1 X2025 -0.12147951  0.1070965  0.002754518  0.4196231  0.4445853 -1.316908124
# 5: cty1 X2030  0.07089875 -0.0499600  0.001647943 -0.5836272 -0.4664951  0.598269113
# 6: cty2 X2010  0.98834150  1.0685221  1.066418900         NA         NA           NA
# 7: cty2 X2015 -0.53951661  0.9055298 -0.904717849 -0.5458808  0.8474600 -0.848370044
# 8: cty2 X2020 -0.28949668  0.2408908 -0.002091656  0.5365853  0.2660220  0.002311942
# 9: cty2 X2025 -0.12147951  0.1070965  0.002754518  0.4196231  0.4445853 -1.316908124
#10: cty2 X2030  0.07089875 -0.0499600  0.001647943 -0.5836272 -0.4664951  0.598269113
#11: cty3 X2010  0.98834150  1.0685221  1.066418900         NA         NA           NA
#12: cty3 X2015 -0.53951661  0.9055298 -0.904717849 -0.5458808  0.8474600 -0.848370044
#13: cty3 X2020 -0.28949668  0.2408908 -0.002091656  0.5365853  0.2660220  0.002311942
#14: cty3 X2025 -0.12147951  0.1070965  0.002754518  0.4196231  0.4445853 -1.316908124
#15: cty3 X2030  0.07089875 -0.0499600  0.001647943 -0.5836272 -0.4664951  0.598269113
```

-checking with the values of 'dt.subset' for the first 'cty' after applying the OP's function

```
dt.subset
#            f1       x.f1
#1:  0.98834150         NA
#2: -0.53951661 -0.5458808
#3: -0.28949668  0.5365853
#4: -0.12147951  0.4196231
#5:  0.07089875 -0.5836272
```

---

Or we can do this with `Map`

```
dt[, (foods) := Map(function(x, y) accumulate(y[-1], `*`, .init = x[1]),
           mget(foods), mget(x.foods)), by = .(cty)]
dt
#     cty  year          f1         f2           f3       x.f1       x.f2         x.f3
# 1: cty1 X2010  0.98834150  1.0685221  1.066418900         NA         NA           NA
# 2: cty1 X2015 -0.53951661  0.9055298 -0.904717849 -0.5458808  0.8474600 -0.848370044
# 3: cty1 X2020 -0.28949668  0.2408908 -0.002091656  0.5365853  0.2660220  0.002311942
# 4: cty1 X2025 -0.12147951  0.1070965  0.002754518  0.4196231  0.4445853 -1.316908124
# 5: cty1 X2030  0.07089875 -0.0499600  0.001647943 -0.5836272 -0.4664951  0.598269113
# 6: cty2 X2010  0.98834150  1.0685221  1.066418900         NA         NA           NA
# 7: cty2 X2015 -0.53951661  0.9055298 -0.904717849 -0.5458808  0.8474600 -0.848370044
# 8: cty2 X2020 -0.28949668  0.2408908 -0.002091656  0.5365853  0.2660220  0.002311942
# 9: cty2 X2025 -0.12147951  0.1070965  0.002754518  0.4196231  0.4445853 -1.316908124
#10: cty2 X2030  0.07089875 -0.0499600  0.001647943 -0.5836272 -0.4664951  0.598269113
#11: cty3 X2010  0.98834150  1.0685221  1.066418900         NA         NA           NA
#12: cty3 X2015 -0.53951661  0.9055298 -0.904717849 -0.5458808  0.8474600 -0.848370044
#13: cty3 X2020 -0.28949668  0.2408908 -0.002091656  0.5365853  0.2660220  0.002311942
#14: cty3 X2025 -0.12147951  0.1070965  0.002754518  0.4196231  0.4445853 -1.316908124
#15: cty3 X2030  0.07089875 -0.0499600  0.001647943 -0.5836272 -0.4664951  0.598269113
```

---

Or if we are using `cumprod` (there were some errors in the OP's `f.cumprod` function).  It could be changed to

```
f.cumprod <- function(x, y)  cumprod(c(x[1], y[-1]))
dt[, (foods) := Map(f.cumprod,  mget(foods), mget(x.foods)), by = .(cty)]
dt
#     cty  year          f1         f2           f3       x.f1       x.f2         x.f3
# 1: cty1 X2010  0.98834150  1.0685221  1.066418900         NA         NA           NA
# 2: cty1 X2015 -0.53951661  0.9055298 -0.904717849 -0.5458808  0.8474600 -0.848370044
# 3: cty1 X2020 -0.28949668  0.2408908 -0.002091656  0.5365853  0.2660220  0.002311942
# 4: cty1 X2025 -0.12147951  0.1070965  0.002754518  0.4196231  0.4445853 -1.316908124
# 5: cty1 X2030  0.07089875 -0.0499600  0.001647943 -0.5836272 -0.4664951  0.598269113
# 6: cty2 X2010  0.98834150  1.0685221  1.066418900         NA         NA           NA
# 7: cty2 X2015 -0.53951661  0.9055298 -0.904717849 -0.5458808  0.8474600 -0.848370044
# 8: cty2 X2020 -0.28949668  0.2408908 -0.002091656  0.5365853  0.2660220  0.002311942
# 9: cty2 X2025 -0.12147951  0.1070965  0.002754518  0.4196231  0.4445853 -1.316908124
#10: cty2 X2030  0.07089875 -0.0499600  0.001647943 -0.5836272 -0.4664951  0.598269113
#11: cty3 X2010  0.98834150  1.0685221  1.066418900         NA         NA           NA
#12: cty3 X2015 -0.53951661  0.9055298 -0.904717849 -0.5458808  0.8474600 -0.848370044
#13: cty3 X2020 -0.28949668  0.2408908 -0.002091656  0.5365853  0.2660220  0.002311942
#14: cty3 X2025 -0.12147951  0.1070965  0.002754518  0.4196231  0.4445853 -1.316908124
#15: cty3 X2030  0.07089875 -0.0499600  0.001647943 -0.5836272 -0.4664951  0.598269113
```

NOTE: The values are the same for each 'cty' because the example dataset values are the same for each 'cty'

Comment: This is a great answer; detailed, multiple options, corrected errors in my question! I'm going to say it despite the rules  - Many thanks!